# Javascript ReferenceError while using jest.mock method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to understand the jest unit testing framework in Javascript and specifically mocking modules part by following this article: https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c However, when I try to use `jest.mock()` to mock my module, I get this error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

This is my math module that I am trying to mock:

```
export function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}


export function subtract(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

Here's my test file:

```
import * as mathlib from '../mathlib';
import * as math from '../math';
import {jest, describe, test, expect} from '@jest/globals';

jest.mock('../math.js');

describe('math', () => {
  test('adds numbers', () => {
    mathlib.doAdd(1,2);
    expect(math.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1,2);
  })
})
```

Here's the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "sample package to learn jest",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "author": "rakesh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.3.1"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: How about your nodejs version? https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules

Comment: I am using version 14.17.5 of nodejs